# Flutter, dart: what's the difference between these snippets of code?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-image-picker

Code snippet A is working, but not snippet B. I check variable "image"s data type with print(), both A and B's image (variable) has a datatype (XFile), not a Null. But B is still not working....

```
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

print(image);

// Code snippet A
if (image == null) return null;
return File(image.path);

// Code snippet B
return File(image!.path);
```

Comment: "A" returns `null` when `image` is `null`. "B" throws an exception when `image` is `null`.

Comment: Because image variable can be null, so if you receive null with code B, it will return an exception !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of your code snippet A is:

If the `image` variable is null it will return null otherwise it will return the `image` variable.

The meaning of your code snippet B is:

It returns the `image` variable, although the `image` variable may be null.

If you use code snippet B, you use `!` and change the variable from a nullable type to a non-nullable type, and the variable is actually empty (has no value) and you can't use `.path` so it returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

`image` can be `null`, In Code `A` you check for `nullable` value so you won't get `exception`, but in code `B` you are using `!` on `nullable` value which is wrong.

If you look for short form you can try this:

```
return image == null ? null : File(image.path);
```